# angular 2 ngrx/store unavailable data breaks async pipe

Tags: angular, ngrx

If my initial state is something like

```
export const initialState: State = {
  release: '',
  shape: '',
  story: '',
  keyFeatures: [''],
  colors: []
};

export function reducer(state = initialState, action): State {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "UPDATE_PRODUCT": return Object.assign({}, action.payload || state);
        case "UPDATE_COLOR": 
            return Object.assign({}, state, {currentColor: action.payload.currentColor, imagePaths: action.payload.imagePaths})
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

and the the component is consuming the state like this

```
<img class="glassesImg" [images]="paths | async" >

_store.select('product')
      .subscribe((product: State) => {
        this.collection = product.collection;
        this.release = product.release;
        this.sku = product.sku;
        this.paths = product.imagePaths;
    })
```

I'm getting the error "Invalid argument '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'" when there isn't any available data. I'd expect that the AsyncPipe simply can subscribe to '' as a valid string value for that property? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the `async` pipe with normal sync values? `async` needs to be used with `Observable` or `Promise`, but `paths` is just a normal value type.

If you want to use `async`, you could do something like

```
<something [blah]="(model$ | async)?.someProperty">

class Component {
  model$
  ...
  this.model$ = store.select(..)
}
```

Or just don't use `async` and just initialize your component properties with a default value, until the first value comes in from the store.

Comment: I've already tried what you suggested, and that wasn't able to render the images like the code I already had did. I also tried just removing the async pipe altogether, but with no success.

Comment: And what exactly is `[images]`, and why should it work with the `img` tag?